# Enable Log TeamCity Tests - UWP

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, uwp, teamcity, jetbrains-ide

I have a problem when I try to write in console application of TeamCity.
In a Unit Test Project (classic) if I use *Trace.WriteLine*, TeamCity recognized that and write value in her console. Unique case when TeamCity write in her console are test Fail and I send a message, such as:

```
Assert.IsTrue(false, "My message");
```

In my project, Unit Test(Windows Universal), I try to use Trace, but this does not exist, I try to user *System.Diagnostic.Debug.Writeline*, but this only write in Visual Studio console when I run my tests in Debug mode.

Someone help me to write logs, when I execute my tests in my Unit Test (Windows Universal)?

**Notes:**

- TeamCity Professional 10.0.3 (build 42434)
- Agent: Windows 10
- Project: Unit Test App (Windows Universal)
- Framework Tests: MSTestFramework.Universal

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Console.WriteLine() will work!

Comment: @Jocke, how to you use Console.Writeline() in Universal Project?
Please explain. Thanks